# How to see/edit excel macro in hidden workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with an auto_run macro. Within the autorun macro, the workbook is either hidden or closed.

How can I enable editing of the macros without having the macro run and lock me out. Right now I am locked out of even seeing my code.

Answer (score 3):

In Excel, disable macros (see [change macro security settings](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-macro-security-settings-in-excel-HP010096919.aspx)).

Comment: Disabling macros prevents you from seeing/editing the macro directly from that workbook. This is not a solution. I've found a solution, but don't have the reputation to post it, yet.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? After disabling macros from the "macro security" dialog box I'm still able to see my code on Office 2007. Also post you solution here, maybe will it help others with the same problem.